# Como trazer uma consulta do banco de acordo com um select, para um input

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, banco-de-dados, json

Quero colocar a um valor do banco ao selecionar o veiculo, ate consegui colocar um valor qualquer, mas não sei buscar no banco via AJAX ou JSON

[image: Exemplo]

[image: Exemplo 2]

Comment: Bem vindo Breno, para melhorar a sua chance de obter a resposta desejada, por favor de uma olhada na central de ajuda sobre como construir a sua pergunta de maneira que facilite aos outros usuários te ajudar.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score 0):

Pra fazer uma busca no banco vc precisa montar ela em php em uma outra página aí vc pode passar os parâmetros via Get ou Post no Ajax e obter o retorno da consulta